# maximum value of $f(x)= 13x^3 + 5y^2 + 6yz + 5z^2$

Tags: calculus, optimization

Find the maximum and minimum values of
$ f(x, y, z) = 13x^3 + 5y^2 + 6yz + 5z^2 $on the solid ball $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 ≤ 1$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The method of Lagrange's multiplier might be useful.

`http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier`